# Open report chart in visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce

Hi i am tring to open reports chart in visualforce page but i am getting error:

this is me visualforce code:

```
<apex:page showheader="false">
<base target="_blank" />
        <analytics:reportChart reportId="report_id"  size="large" ></analytics:reportChart>
</apex:page>
```

**The report chart is no longer available because the report has been moved to a personal folder. To display it, drag the report to a shared folder.**

this only error how to solve this problem...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check your report id....It needs to be valid. And ensure your report is saved into a public folder.

Comment: This looks like accsssibility issue, trying to save in public folder or make sure to add in a folder for which running user is having complete access.

Comment: This is a permission issue.  Don’t forget to save the report in a public folder (like Unfiled Reports). Give a shot again and let us know.

Comment: I Done the same process as per your suggestion . it is showing error message as per the below :- **
You can't view the report chart because its report, report type, or chart has been deleted**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you want to display a report chart in VisualForce page, the user should have appropriate permission to view the report as well.

**Try the following:**

- Take the `report_id` and go the report page as 'https://mydomain.salesforce.com/[report_id]'
- Edit the report and click on Save Properties
- Make sure you save the report into accessible public folder (like Unfiled Reports)

Once you refresh the VF page you should be able to see the report.

**Update:**

- The problem is you don't have any charts in the report to display

**Add Chart:**

- Click on customize on the report and click on **Add Chart**
- Save the report and come back here, you should be able to see the report

> Its really weird that the message what it was displaying is mis-leading from what is really happening.

[image]

Comment: From your comment, it seems that your Admin or some other user delete the report. Contact your Admin for the same. You can try using some other report which you having access for testing purpose.

Comment: Sorry Ididn't understand  first i need to tell what i did _i created one report with summary formate in my personal custom reports again i drag that report to unfilled public report then open that report i used that report id only used in visualforce page _

Comment: Take report_id and put it into your domain as 'your_domain.com/report_id' and tell me whats happening ?

Comment: Opening Marchandise Report page ...

Comment: Updated  my report detail page and vf page screen shots can oyu please tell me where error occuring...

Comment: Can you click on customize and click on properties in that window

Comment: can you check once updated properties window....

Comment: already i changed report folder personal custom report to unfilled public report..Now report is in unfilled public report but error showing report deleted like that can u please tell why this error showing....please help on this.

Comment: Can you check whether you are using 15 digit or 18 digit report_id. If you are using 18 digit can you try with 15 digit ? Just a try

Comment: I am using 15 digits report_id only...can you tell me any permssions require to show in visualforce page..already we share report in public report folder we need any other permissions required?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36208/discussion-between-karthikselva-and-user123).